# Mongoose query via Angular variable

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I´m trying to query my mongoose model with an angular variable - an email adress.
I´ve got a variable from `passport` with contains the email `<%= user.local.email %>`.

The `$http.get`for my Model looks like this:

```
app.get('/profile/project/:mail', function (req, res, next){
    Project.findOne(req.params.mail, function (err, doc){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

I can´t figure out how to pass the mail adress with the angular controller, to the GET request.

My try:

```
$http.get('/profile/project/' + <%= user.local.email %>).then(function (res){
                $scope.project = res.data;
            });
        });
```

Setting the `findOne` parameter to a fixed mail adress worked, but I´ve got no idea how to pass the mail adress with the angular controller.
Hope you can help me.
Best regards, David

**Update using passport**
Getting near the solution, but now I only get the first data entry of my DB.
Sum it up, my route:

```
app.get('/profile/project/', function (req, res, next){
    Project.findOne(req.user.local.email, function (err, doc){
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!doc) return next(new Error('cant find'));
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc); 
    });
});
```

My angular controller:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('projectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
                $scope.project = res.data;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Passport works,I can log in and show the email address on the profile page. But with this route I´m just getting the first [0] entry from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want angular to pass this variable?

If it's in passport, then it's likely the user's own email? If so then you should just look it up entirely on the backend.

If the email is really being passed from angular, then it doesn't make sense to have it in passport at all, and you would just pass it as a js var.

**Edit**

`findOne` should only return one result. Maybe you need to use `find` if you are trying to get multiple records.

Comment: This makes absolute sense! Tried it out, and I got some data - BUT the not the right set. I implemented it like this: 'Project.findOne(passport.email, function (err, doc){...'

Comment: if you have the middleware set up correctly, then you should just be able to do `req.user.local.email`

Comment: Edited my first post for you

Comment: I´m getting nuts ... I´m expecting just one record, so findOne works for me ... but I´ve got no idea, where the problem is. Can I specify the problem for you somehow?

Comment: ah, it's always returning the first row of the db you mean?

Comment: Yes it was always the first row, but now it works. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Big thanks to @Austin_Greco!

Route:

```
app.get('/profile/project/', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next){
    Project.findOne({'author' : req.user.local.email}, function (err, doc){
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!doc) return next(new Error('cant find'));
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc); 
    });
});
```

Angular Controller:

```
$http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
    $scope.project = res.data;
});
```